# Load external OGG file into Unity WebGL build at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, audioclip

I am trying to load some sounds in OGG format into my game at runtime in a WebGL build. I use a WWW class to fetch the file which has an ".ogg" extension and then I call `www.audioClip` to get the downloaded file. This works on other platforms but fails in WebGL.

Unity throws up this error message: **"Streaming of 'ogg' on this platform is not supported"**. Strange since I am not trying to stream it, and I have tried explicitly calling `GetAudioClip(false, false, AudioType.OGGVORBIS)` and got the same result.

I have tried converting my OGG file to AAC (with M4A and MP4 extensions) and loading this with `www.audioClip` (error that it cannot determine the file type from the URL) and `www.GetAudioClip(false, false, AudioType.MPEG)` (no error but also no sound). The closest thing to a solution I've seen online is to use MP3 instead but I don't want to do this for licensing reasons.

Is WebGL in Unity restricted to audio assets that are build into the application?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
WWW data = new WWW (url); yield return data;
AudioClip ac = data.GetAudioClipCompressed(false, AudioType.AUDIOQUEUE) as AudioClip;
if(ac != null)
{
    ac.name = "mySoundFile.ogg";
    gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().clip = ac;
}
else
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource> ().clip = null;
    Debug.Log("no audio found.");
}
```

works for me with .ogg files.